# service worker we are facing cache issue

Tags: caching, service-worker, offline-storage

I am a fresher for service worker. I am trying to implement static and dynamic caching.

When I add the single file to the static cache request, it is taking all the files whatever I have. Currently, all the files are running from the service worker when I started from the offline mode. Please someone help me.

This is the code I have in index.html.

```
       self.addEventListener('install',function(event)
      {
      console.log('[service worker]Installing service 
       worker....',event);
      event.waitUntil(caches.open('static')
      .then(function(cache)
      {
          console.log('[Service Worker] Precaching App Shell');
          cache.addAll([
                       '/',
                       '/signin.html',
                       ]); 
    })
  )
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In **Static caching** some of the requests(pages) are cached(saved in Browser's local storage), it is generally done in `install` event of Service Worker. Whereas in **Dynamic caching** pages & files are cached whenever you request(fetch) for them hence, it makes use of `fetch` event of Service Worker.

So, in your `install` event when you add `'/'` in `cache.addAll` service worker adds all the files and resources needed to display `'/'` ie root directory.

Now, to make use of those cached files and to implement **Dynamic Caching** you'll need to implement something like this:

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function (event) {

    event.respondWith(
      caches.match(event.request)       // if data has been cached already
        .then(function (response) {
          if (response) {
            return response;
          } else {              // else fetch from internet & cache in DYNAMIC cache
            return fetch(event.request)
              .then(function (res) {
                return caches.open(CACHE_DYNAMIC_NAME)
                  .then(function (cache) {
                    cache.put(event.request.url, res.clone());
                    return res;
                  })
              })
              .catch(function (err) {           //fallback mechanism
                return caches.open(CACHE_STATIC_NAME)
                  .then(function (cache) {
                    if (event.request.headers.get('accept').includes('text/html')) {
                      return cache.match('/offline.html');
                    }
                  });
              });
          }
        })
    );
});
```

**NOTE:** To avoid over crowding your local storage you might wanna implement some strategy before actually saving the file in storage.
For more info read [this](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/instant-and-offline/offline-cookbook/) to learn more about strategies.

Comment: once we done with dynamic caching every thing will work as expected??

Comment: Yeah, it should. You can always log out and see where you are struck.

Comment: Ok thank you..once i got any difficulty in dynamic caching i will let you know

Comment: Glad to help :) Also don't forget to accept/upvote questions and answers on SO that help